# utility class's static member (null) lifecycle

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, static

I have a utility class that has constants and static methods.
Furthermore, that has one static field.

```
public class MyUtil implements IMyUtil {
   public static String IS_DEBUG = false;
   ...
   private static MyEnumType mMyEnum;

   ...
   // static getter setter methods for mMyEnum
}
```

I have two fragments (**FragmentA** and **FragmentB** for the sake of simplicity).
**FragmentA** set the `mMyEnum` value, and then later use it with the getter method. When the user presses a button, I show **FragmentB**.
In the `onActiviyCreated()` method of FragmentB I get the mMyEnum value.

On my test devices everything is ok. But in the Google Play Console I see a bunch of `NullPointerException` errors at this line:

```
String testString = MyUtil.getMyEnum().getSomeStringValue();
```

I can't figure it out why can be `myEnum` null on that line and why I can't reproduce it. MyUtil obviously can't be null, `getSomeStringValue()` can be null, but it doesn't throw a `NullPointerException`, so the only myEnum can be null. But why? And if it can be null how can I reproduce it?

Thank you.

**UPDATE #1:**
Play shows a wide range of devices (Samsung A3, S6, S7, S8, LG X, G3, Huawei P9 etc.) and API versions (5.0 -> 7.1). Full stack trace is:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2984)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3045)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14 (ActivityThread.java)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1642)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:154)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6776)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:1496)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1386)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: 
  at com.mycompany.fragment.FragmentB.onActivityCreated (FragmentB.java:35)
  at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performActivityCreated (Fragment.java:2089)
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState (FragmentManagerImpl.java:1133)
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState (FragmentManagerImpl.java:1290)
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState (FragmentManagerImpl.java:1272)
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated (FragmentManagerImpl.java:2149)
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated (FragmentController.java:201)
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart (FragmentActivity.java:600)
  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart (AppCompatActivity.java:178)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart (Instrumentation.java:1256)
  at android.app.Activity.performStart (Activity.java:6972)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2937)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3045)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14 (ActivityThread.java)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1642)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:154)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6776)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:1496)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1386)
```

Comment: Did you see the devices and information of those devices causing the crash? Usually Google Play, Google, or whoever I don't remember right now makes monkey testing on random apps that crashes randomly (usually because they don't maintain activities). Let me try to get a similar crash from Crashlytics, I'll post it here. In the meanwhile, could you answer to these two questions? 1.- Are you logging your crashes externally (Crashlytics, Firebase). 2.- Can you provide the full information of those crashes from Google Play Console?

Comment: Thank you. Updated my question.

Comment: I've been assuming you mean NullPointerException by NullException. If it's something else, let us know

Comment: Yes sorry, I mean NullPointerException. I'm trying to 'slow down' the system. I will post the results, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Long-lived Static members present a problem because Android may have freed memory and removed this value at some time (when no fragment is active with a reference to it). You also haven't explicitly said whether you can get to FragmentB without setting a value from FragmentA first, so this could also be your problem.

Additional note - a constant should be constant - so should have the `final` keyword.

My suggested solution would be to get rid of this bad architecture where two components are relying on an outside god-object to maintain their state. Pass your enum value as an Extra in the intent.

You can write to the bundle with

```
public static final String KEY_ENUM = "MyEnumKey";

bundle.putString(KEY_ENUM, myEnum.name()):
```

and then read it back with

```
Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
MyEnumTypemyEnum = MyEnumType.valueOf(bundle.getString(FragmentA.KEY_ENUM));
```

Another suggestion is to ensure that myEnum is never null (which by default it is). Declare it like:

```
private static MyEnumType mMyEnum = MyEnumType.MY_DEFAULT_VALUE;
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. You can't get FragmentB wiithout FragmentA (A is a login screen). I can't set a final keyword, because myEnum get a value once after the user press the login button.
Send the appropriate value via intent extra would be a good choice, but I really want to reproduce the error (to learn from it and I want to know, that the fix is fixed the original problem). Maybe I can't reproduce it intentionally?

Comment: That was a reference to your actual constant - IS_DEBUG. What happens if you are on FragmentB, you switch app and do high memory stuff (run youtube and an antivirus scan and then tinder, etc.) and then switch back to your app?

Comment: So far I haven't got a NullException, my device has just slowed down.

Comment: I solved the problem with adding parameter with intent extra, so far it's seems ok (no crash). Thank you for your help!